# PHP RegEx - * is not greedy enough

Tags: php, regex

I execute this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^([^\|]*)(?!\|\|Read)/','$1||Read',"test||Read");
echo "$string<br>";
$string = preg_replace('/^([^\|]*)(?!.*Read)/','$1||Read',"test||Read");
echo "$string<br>";
```

and I get this:

```
tes||Readt||Read
test||Read
```

The idea is to add "||Read" after a string (not containing a pipe) if it doesn't exist.
So why does the * in the first RegEx consume only "tes"?

The second RegEx works because the first * consumes "tes" and the second * in the assertion matches "t||" .

Comment: You description of what *should* happen is really poor, at least I can't make sense of it.

Comment: It should add "||Read" at the end of a line if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Then `preg_replace('/$(?<!\|\|Read)/', '||Read', $str)` is the most efficient way to do this. You don't even need back-references or possessive matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it more greedy or ["possessive"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) by adding a `+` plus after the `*` quantifier:

```
 ([^\|]*+)
```

So your code becomes:

```
 $string = preg_replace('/^([^\|]*+)(?!\|\|Read)/','$1||Read',"test||Read");
```

Which for your test case doesn't leave the `t` over.

In your case, the `||Read` should always occur at the line end? If so, you could also just use `^(.*?)$` for matching, and assert the line end instead `(?<!Read)$`.

Comment: Oh .. nice. I didn't know that you can use *+. Yes, "||Read" is at the line end, and there are probably many ways this can accomplished. I just found weird that * stopped after 3 chars.